# create complex table header in tableau sheet

Tags: tableau-api

As you can see (below) I have LastYear, CurrentYear, %YOY (calculated)  for NetSaleAll, NetSaleAll(New), and NetSaleAll(Retained), so totally 9 measures in the source (different names of course). So question is how to add  NetSaleAll, NetSaleAll(New), and NetSaleAll(Retained) text for related measures  (LastYear, CurrentYear, %YOY (calculated))?

[image]

Comment: as per my understanding you need LastYear(NetSalesAll) is that correct?

Comment: No i am trying to add text headers (NetSaleAll, NetSaleAll(New), and NetSaleAll(Retained)) on top of the measures. If in excel, it's pretty easy, just select 3 cells above each group of the measures, and combine the cells and enter the header text.

Comment: can you share tableau work book

Comment: not sure how to add a tableau work book here, but here is a link to my question on tableau forum, scroll to the bottom for the attached workbook https://community.tableau.com/thread/269724

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by creating headers in one sheet and data in other sheet and then in dashboard combining both sheets.

I have made changes and attached the book in same link.

[image]

Comment: This works for static text table. But in my project it has a scroll bar at the bottom of the text table due to too many columns, so the header sheet won't scroll while the text table will. The attachement is just to show an idea, in my real project, the text table has more than 10 columns.

Comment: Is it possible for you make changes in database?

Comment: Create a column in table from where data is extracted and then write header names for specific measures so you are mapping the header names with measures in database. Now in tableau drag the header column on to column shelf